# Wrong php_sufix config variable in MAMP

Tags: php, mongodb, mamp, pecl

I've just installed MAMP and I'm trying to install the Mongo extension via `pecl` but I'm getting an error:

```
jonesy:bin Billy$ sudo pecl install mongo
downloading mongo-1.4.4.tgz ...
Starting to download mongo-1.4.4.tgz (141,242 bytes)
..............................done: 141,242 bytes
84 source files, building
WARNING: php_bin /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/php appears to have a suffix /php5.5.3/bin/php, but config variable php_suffix does not match
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20121113
Zend Module Api No:      20121212
Zend Extension Api No:   220121212
Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.
```

I'm not sure what's going on here.

My pecl directory is:

```
jonesy:bin Billy$ which pecl
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/pecl
```

PHP version is `5.5.3`

I downloaded the latest version of PHP into the following directory and ran `./configure` as MAMP doesn't come with all modules, etc.

`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/include/php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your actual issue is that pecl can't find autoconf:

> Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
>   $PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.

Try searching on that basis and you should find what you need - it seems that at least once person has just compiled and installed autoconf:

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/autoconf-latest.tar.gz
```

untar that and cd

```
./configure
make
sudo make install;
```

(from http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=3980#p80224)